# number counting animation in textview

Tags: android

I am developing a game application in android. I am struck at Scorecard implementation.
I want to display score in a textview as the numbers are continously counting for movement.
for example : suppose user crosses one obstacle and score for that obstacle is 200. Then numbers in scorecard should count from 0 to 200 smoothly and then will stop at 200.
I have seen this type of animation in score card of papiJump.

Please guide me.

Comment: I am thinking of using Handler to count from 1 to 200 and display it on the textview. Is my idea correct.

Comment: be careful with one thing: if you keep hand on the UI Thread for too long, you'll be ANRed. So an AsyncTask may be more appropriate

Answer (score 4):

```
ValueAnimator animator   = ValueAnimator.ofInt(int start, int end);
              animator.setDuration(2000);
              animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        textView.setText(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
                    }
                });

                animator.start();
```

Comment: Add some description also what it will do or how to apply on textview.

Comment: This function is pretty easy to use , it will increase integer value on textView from 0 to some value with animation.
Set you range in start and end  e.g 0 to 300 and set duration value e.g 2000  So the value increment process willhappen in 2 secs.
Learn more https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void animateTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView textview)
 {
  DecelerateInterpolator decelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(0.8f);
        int start = Math.min(initialValue, finalValue);
        int end = Math.max(initialValue, finalValue);
        int difference = Math.abs(finalValue - initialValue);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        for (int count = start; count <= end; count++) {
            int time = Math.round(decelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation((((float) count) / difference)) * 100) * count;
            final int finalCount = ((initialValue > finalValue) ? initialValue - count : count);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textview.setText(finalCount + "");
                }
            }, time);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: initially set initial value =0 final value is based on the movement after that set initial value = last assigned value and final value can be changed based on the movement position